# How to check if the exact vector is a subset of another vector of a list

Tags: r, subset

I skimmed similar posts and I have tried them but I still could not solve my problem.

I have a list of vector such as following

```
y2 <- c(0,0,NA,0,0,0,0)
y <- c(0,0,0,NA,NA,0)
x <- c(0,0,0,0)
li <-list(y2,y,x)
```

I am trying to drop the vector from the list `li`, if an exact vector is a subset of another one.

For example, in my case I should have `y2` and `y` as result and have `x` dropped from the list since `x` is an exact subset of `y2`.

I wrote the following script but it just gives the y2 as result, and ignores `y`:

```
UniquePath <- function(PATHS)
{
  for(j in length(PATHS):1)
  {
    for(i in 1:length(PATHS))
    {
      if((i!=j)&(isTRUE(all(is.element(PATHS[[j]],PATHS[[i]])))))
      {
        PATHS<-PATHS[-j]
        break
      }
      else
      {
        next
      }
    }
  }
  return(PATHS)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that because `0` is four times in `x`, `0` should also be 4 times in `y` or `y2`?

Comment: @Heikki, Yes. since x is composed of four zeros and also y2 consists 4 zeros, so we drop the x vector

Comment: Does the order of vectors matter in the list?

Comment: @EsterSilva Can you comment on what should be the result for the following data: `x <- c(0,0,0,0); y <- c(0,NA,0,0,0); y2 <- c(NA,NA,0,0,0,0); l <- list(x,y,y2)` (here `x` is a *subset* of `y` and `y` is a *subset* of `y2`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be (assuming there are no ";" in your string)

```
# make li unique
li <- unique(li)
# collapse each unique list element to a length-1 string surrounded by ";" 
x <- sapply(li, function(x) paste0(";", paste(x, collapse = ";"), ";"))
# check each element, if this is found somewhere in any other element
li[sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) !any(grepl(x[i], x[-i], fixed = TRUE)))]
# [[1]]
# [1]  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  0  0  0 NA NA  0
```

However, it seems that OP should make up a larger example and clarify some of the questions brought up in comments to other answers.

Note: in this answer I define x as a subset of y if and only if the exact sequence of x is present in y without any other elements inbetween. That's how I understood the question.

Comment: I found the same answer but too late. I will delete mine. I just think you can make the second line shorter, it would still work : `lapply(li,function(x)toString(x))`

Comment: @denis, there's a reason why I used those two pastes. If you just use `toString` the result can be wrong since we are only partially matching the strings.

Comment: I might not be getting this (apologies!) but why wouldn't something like: `temp <- sapply(li, paste0, collapse = "") ` and `li[sapply(temp, function(x) sum(grepl(x, temp)) == 1)]` work?

Comment: Think of some other numbers than just 0. Then, using `collapse = ""` makes no sense since you cannot differentiate whether a "010" entry is "0,1,0" or "0,10", for example. That's just one problem with that code. @User2321

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
uniquePath <- function(l){
  idxs <- 1:length(l)
  tmp <- lapply(l, table, useNA='always')
  l2 <- lapply(idxs, function(i){
    res <- l[[i]]
    for(j in idxs[-i]){
      if ( all(res %in% l[[j]]) & all(tmp[[i]] <= tmp[[j]])){ 
        res <- NULL; break 
      }
    }
    res
  })
  Filter(Negate(is.null), l2)
}
```

Some examples:

```
y2 <- c(0,0,NA,0,0,0,0); y <- c(0,0,0,NA,NA,0); x <- c(0,0,0,0)
li <-list(y2 = y2,y = y,x = x)
## This is your example, where x is subset of both y and y2
uniquePath(li)
# [[1]]
# [1]  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0
#
# [[2]]
# [1]  0  0  0 NA NA  0

x <- c(0,0,0,0); y <- c(0,NA,0,0,0); y2 <- c(NA,NA,0,0,0,0)
l <- list(x,y,y2)
## Here x is a subset of y and y is a subset of y2
uniquePath(l)
# [[1]]
# [1] NA NA  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following using a recursive function.

```
# Your sample data
y2 <- c(0,0,NA,0,0,0,0)
y <- c(0,0,0,NA,NA,0)
x <- c(0,0,0,0)
li <-list(y2 = y2,y = y,x = x)
```

I define a recursive function `collapseList` that recursively removes list entries if they are an ordered subset of other list entries.

```
# Recursive function to collapse entries
collapseList <- function(lst) {
    s <- sapply(lst, paste, collapse = "");
    if (sum(grepl(s[1], s)) > 1) {
        lst <- lst[-1];
        collapseList(lst);
    }
    else lst;
}
```

Output based on your sample list:

```
# Order list by number of list elements
li <- li[order(sapply(li, length))];

li <- collapseList(li);
li;
#$y
#[1]  0  0  0 NA NA  0
#
#$y2
#[1]  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0
```

---

@storaged example

```
li <- list(
    x = c(0,0,0,0), 
    y = c(0,NA,0,0,0), 
    y2 = c(NA,NA,0,0,0,0));

li <- li[order(sapply(li, length))];
collapseList(li);
#$y
#[1]  0 NA  0  0  0
#
#$y2
#[1] NA NA  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: As far as I understand the problem. This solution does not work for all cases. Check: `x <- c(0,0,0,0); y <- c(0,NA,0,0,0); y2 <- c(NA,NA,0,0,0,0); l <- list(x,y,y2)` In the output you have a list with two elements and one is the subset of the other.

Comment: @storaged Quite possible that I misunderstood. But for the example you give I end up with a list of two vectors (`y` and `y2`), while `x` was removed. That seems consistent with what (I think) OP wants. `y` and `y2` are no subsets of each other.

Comment: @storaged I've updated my solution to account for your example.

Comment: Hm, wait, `y = c(0,NA,0,0,0); y2 = c(NA,NA,0,0,0,0)`. Isn't `y` the subset of `y2`? Maybe I got the question wrong.

Comment: @storaged I think I see what you mean. I understood OP to define a subset as a complete vector (like `x = c(0, 0, 0, 0)`) that is part of a larger vector (like `y2 = c(0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0)`). In that case, remove the smaller vector from the list. Perhaps OP can clarify...

Comment: Ok, right, now I see your point! So the question is: If we look for a *subset* or a *subsequence*.

Comment: @storaged Yes, I agree.

Comment: @storaged Perhaps you could suggest your example to OP and ask him to clarify on the expected output.